# How do I write a regex that matches the beginning of the line or NOT a character?

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I write a regular expression in which matches something where the last character is a dash and the preceding character is not a dash or the beginning of the line.  So this expression shoudl match

```
"-"
```

as shoudl

```
"ab-"
```

but this should not

```
"---"
```

I tried the below but I'm not matching anything

```
2.4.0 :012 > word = "abc-"
 => "abc-" 
2.4.0 :013 > word =~ /(^|\^\-)\-$/
 => nil
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `a---b-` which should be a valid string as far as I can see.

Comment: "the last character is a dash and the preceding character is not a dash or the beginning of the line" Shouldn't "-" not match since the dash is preceded by the beginning of the line?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what "the preceding character is not..the beginning of the line" means. This suggests there is a preceding character--meaning the size of the string is at least `2`--but since when is the beginning of a string (not the beginning of "something") a character? That sentence is an abomination. If `"a--"` is not a match, the examples suggest you mean, "How do I write a regular expression that matches a substring at the begining of a given string, ends with a hyphen, contains no other hyphens and is not immediately followed by a hyphen." Is that what you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I got your requirements right, but this does seem to do the trick:

```
regex = /(^|(?!-).*)-$/
%w(- ab- ---).map { |s| s =~ regex }
#=> [0, 0, nil]
```

Check it out on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/vPM8VRUoOb) with some test cases.

Comment: This might match `-a---b-`... I'm not sure if that's within the OP's spec.

Comment: I wasn't sure either, there weren't quite enough examples.

Comment: A downvote with no comment on an accepted answer is not exactly helpful.

Comment: Your regex matches a hyphen at the beginning of a line, but the question prohibits that.

Comment: @Cory: The question actually stated that "-" is ok, despite the textual description potentially reading otherwise. It said "-" and "ab-" SHOULD match. Both of them were included in my Rubular link, so OP was clearly fine with it.

Comment: To quote 'So this expression should match "-" as should "ab-" but this should not "---"''. Confusing as the description may be, my code works for the 3 cases described here.

Comment: Also see the second comment on the OP, which points to the inconsistency between the actual description and the shown results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my go at it:

```
regex = /[^-\A]-\z/
%w(- ab- ---).map { |s| s =~ regex }
 => [nil, 1, nil]
```